# How to make tmux sessions count from 1 instead of 0?

Tags: tmux

I have this setting:

```
# Number windows and panes starting at 1 so that we can jump to
# them easier.
set -g base-index 1
set -g pane-base-index 1
```

But I'd also like to have the same for switching tmux sessions. When I open the tmux session list it still starts on 0. Is it possible to not start session counting from 0 but from 1 instead?

[image: tmux session list]

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). The numbers in parentheses have nothing to do with how tmux counts sessions. See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/755474/108618).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be referring to the *session group index*, which is generated, and not used for telling `tmux` which session you would like to attach to.

It's used in the [template for `list-sessions`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/cmd-list-sessions.c#L31):

```
"#{?session_grouped, (group ,}" \
```

and generated in [`session.c`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/session.c#L549) (and always starts at zero):

```
/* Find session group index. */
u_int
session_group_index(struct session_group *sg)
{
    struct session_group   *sg2;
    u_int           i;

    i = 0;
    TAILQ_FOREACH(sg2, &session_groups, entry) {
        if (sg == sg2)
            return (i);
        i++;
    }

    fatalx("session group not found");
}
```

but that value is used only in formatted output.

Comment: So the current answer is that it's currently not possible except by patching. Sad =/. The thing is, this indexing also ends up taking control of how one does the session switch, it's rather annoying to press 0.

Comment: yes, that's the way I read the code.  Numbering from 1 would be less movement on the keyboard.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the numbers displayed do work as session switching keys, contrary to what you seem to tell that they're not for that.

Answer (score 11):

It's not possible, and it will not be possible in the future. There is [declined feature request](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/769) for `session-base-index`, developers believe that "[It's just not a helpful feature](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/769#issuecomment-383178555)."

Comment: reading through this thread is just.. :eyeroll:

Comment: The feature would not solve the OP's problem. See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/755474/108618).

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr

Skip to the "Solution" section.

---

#### Analysis

There is one big **misunderstanding** here.

Your screenshot was probably taken after <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>, which by default runs the following tmux command:

```
choose-tree -Zs
```

(in a shell you can run it with `tmux choose-tree -Zs`). The numbers in parentheses have *nothing* to do with session IDs or session names. They are just "line numbers" *in the list at the moment*. E.g. the list may look like this:

```
(0) + foo: 2 windows (attached)
(1) + bar: 1 windows
```

but after expanding all the items it may look like this:

```
(0)   - foo: 2 windows (attached)
(1)   ├─> - 0: [tmux]*Z
(2)   │   ├─> 0: man
(3)   │   ├─> 1: bash*
(4)   │   └─> 2: bash
(5)   └─> - 1: bash-
(6)       ├─> 0: bash
(7)       ├─> 2: bash
(8)       ├─> 3: bash
(9)       ├─> 4: bash
(M-a)     ├─> 5: bash
(M-b)     └─> 1: bash*
(M-c) - bar: 1 windows
(M-d) └─> 0: bash*
```

So these "line numbers" are not even numbers, they are keys you can use. Note in the above list only `0` and `M-c` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) correspond to sessions. **The way how tmux counts sessions has nothing to do with these keys, so the [requested (and declined) `session-base-index`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/769) would not solve your problem.** A request to count *lines in `choose-tree`* from 1 would make lot more sense.

You can define your own keys by specifying `-K` to [`choose-tree`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#choose-tree). E.g. a poor man's shift-by-one is implemented by:

```
choose-tree -ZsK '#{e|+:1,#{line}}'
```

which gives you this:

```
(1) + foo: 2 windows (attached)
(2) + bar: 1 windows
```

But this will only attach keys to up to nine lines. My example after expansion looks like this:

```
(1) - foo: 2 windows (attached)
(2) ├─> - 0: [tmux]*Z
(3) │   ├─> 0: man
(4) │   ├─> 1: bash*
(5) │   └─> 2: bash
(6) └─> - 1: bash-
(7)     ├─> 0: bash
(8)     ├─> 2: bash
(9)     ├─> 3: bash
        ├─> 4: bash
        ├─> 5: bash
        └─> 1: bash*
    - bar: 1 windows
    └─> 0: bash*
```

Where there are no `M-a`, `M-b` etc.

In the [code](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/window-tree.c) I've found this:

> ```
> #define WINDOW_TREE_DEFAULT_KEY_FORMAT \
>   "#{?#{e|<:#{line},10}," \
>       "#{line}" \
>   "," \
>       "#{?#{e|<:#{line},36}," \
>               "M-#{a:#{e|+:97,#{e|-:#{line},10}}}" \
>       "," \
>               "" \
>       "}" \
>   "}"
> ```

So I conclude the default value for `choose-tree -K` is:

```
#{?#{e|<:#{line},10},#{line},#{?#{e|<:#{line},36},M-#{a:#{e|+:97,#{e|-:#{line},10}}},}}
```

You can straightforwardly shift by one by replacing each `#{line}` with `#{e|+:1,#{line}}`; or you can reduce the number of computations by changing the hardcoded constants where appropriate:

```
#{?#{e|<:#{line},9},#{e|+:1,#{line}},#{?#{e|<:#{line},35},M-#{a:#{e|+:97,#{e|-:#{line},9}}},}}
```

---

#### Solution

The tmux command will be:

```
choose-tree -ZsK '#{?#{e|<:#{line},9},#{e|+:1,#{line}},#{?#{e|<:#{line},35},M-#{a:#{e|+:97,#{e|-:#{line},9}}},}}'
```

You can test it in a shell inside tmux by invoking `tmux choose-tree …`. If the result is what you want then bind the command to <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> by adding the following line to your `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key s choose-tree -ZsK '#{?#{e|<:#{line},9},#{e|+:1,#{line}},#{?#{e|<:#{line},35},M-#{a:#{e|+:97,#{e|-:#{line},9}}},}}'
```

Keep in mind the file is parsed when a tmux server starts. To affect your already running server you need to pass the command to tmux (e.g. `tmux bind-key s …` in a shell inside tmux) or to reload the altered file (<kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`source-file ~/.tmux.conf`<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

---

#### Example result

```
(1) + foo: 2 windows (attached)
(2) + bar: 1 windows
```

And after expanding:

```
(1)   - foo: 2 windows (attached)
(2)   ├─> - 0: [tmux]*Z
(3)   │   ├─> 0: man
(4)   │   ├─> 1: bash*
(5)   │   └─> 2: bash
(6)   └─> - 1: bash-
(7)       ├─> 0: bash
(8)       ├─> 2: bash
(9)       ├─> 3: bash
(M-a)     ├─> 4: bash
(M-b)     ├─> 5: bash
(M-c)     └─> 1: bash*
(M-d) - bar: 1 windows
(M-e) └─> 0: bash*
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this comment](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/2838#issuecomment-909233245), I came up with this solution to not having a "session-base-index"  option.

```
# {{{ Rename first session if it's "0"

# User options are prefixed with "@"
set-option -g @first-run 1

set-hook -g session-created {
    if-shell -F '#{?@first-run,1,0}' {
        set-option -g @first-run 0
        if-shell -F '#{==:#{session_name},0}' { rename-session 1 }
    }
}
# }}}
```

Of course if you run `tmux new-session -s 0` with no running sessions open, it won't be named `0`.

If you wish to rename *any* new session from "0" to "1", simply use this

```
set-hook -g session-created {
    if-shell -F '#{==:#{session_name},0}' { rename-session 1 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said before, this not supported natively.

The easiest solution is to automatically create `dummy` session.

Simply add to your `.tmux.conf` file this line:

```bash
# Start a dummy session to make real sessions start from 1
new-session -d -s dummy
```

Then, when you start tmux, it will create a session named "dummy" in the background. Your first manually created session will then be numbered 1.

You can change the name from `dummy` to any other.